# Error when adding a new cck field

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

For some reason I get error on lots of pages after adding a simple text field to a content type. And error on pages that doesn't use the content type, and hasn't any relation to the modified content type.

The content type is just a regular form where customers can add some simple data that is later displayed in a view.

The new field is addad to a contenttype that already has som data stored with it.

In the log I found this error message:

Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: disallowed Unicode code point (>= 0xd800 && <= 0xdfff) at offset 1811 in ctools_cleanstring() (line 157 of /home/u/u4144602/www/profiles/nodestream/modules/ctools/includes/cleanstring.inc).

Does anyone know?

It's a drupal 6 installation, a nodestream distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I too got this problem earlier.I've replaced

```
'\x{a80b}\x{a823}-\x{a82b}\x{d800}-\x{f8ff}\x{fb1e}\x{fb29}\x{fd3e}\x{fd3f}'.
```

with

```
'\x{a80b}\x{a823}-\x{a82b}\x{e000}-\x{f8ff}\x{fb1e}\x{fb29}\x{fd3e}\x{fd3f}'.
```

Hope this link might help u... :)

http://drupal.org/node/1878284

http://drupal.org/node/1444006

Comment: Thanks! The error message disappeared. But I still get error http message 500. The error show on some pages after I have added some content i the new cck field. The new cck field doesn't exist in the pages that show the error. Very strange.